# Rails validations with presence and regex format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 situations I don't like when someone leaves a field blank.

1) Field has validation with `presence: true` and a `format` validation:

```
validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, message: 'can only have letters and numbers' }
```

Problem with this is if someone leaves `name` blank, 2 errors are shown. I only want the "name can't be blank" error message shown, doesn't make sense to have "name can only have letters and numbers" error message shown when nothing was entered.

2) Field has validation with only a `format`:

```
validates :name, format: { with: /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, message: 'can only have letters and numbers' }
```

In this case, it's ok for the field to be left blank. Unfortunately, if it is in fact left blank, the user will get an error message because it doesn't pass the regexp. I know I could change the regexp to include an empty string (at least I think I can by prepending `|`). My regexps are normally much more complex than `[[:alnum:]]+` so it would take more than just changing `+` to `*`.

My question is if Rails has a better way to handle the 2 situations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `allow_blank: true` to the options.

```
validates :name, presence: true, 
                 format: { allow_blank: true, with: /\A[[:alnum:]]+\z/, message: 'can only have letters and numbers' }
```